# Notify Gui that data class has changed

Tags: c#

In C#:
I have a data class that is shared amongst several gui classes. I would like all of the gui classes that use it to be notified when some of the properties change, so they can keep the GUI up to date.

In a couple of the properties I have added delegates that the GUI classes can listen to for updates. This seems to work ok.

The problem I have is that more and more of the properties will require GUI notification. When that happens I will have to add more delegates. It also seems that this is adding an extra responsibility to the data class that it has to manage.

Is there some common pattern that I can use to monitor this class to extract this notification responsibility from the data class?

Comment: It is nice to know about this interface, but it still leaves a lot of responsibility in the data class. Would it be recommended to derive a third class from the data class and then implement this interface?

Answer (score 6):

The common way of doing this is for the data class to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

EDIT: If you have a lot of properties, this can lead to very repetitive code in the data class, and if you are binding to a UI, it might be best to use an AOP approach and intercept calls to the properties that you want to notify on. Most IoC containers have support for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is called [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). In .Net, events are one implementation of that pattern. 
For the specific case of observing individual properties, [the INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface should be used (as [@Lee describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123748/notify-gui-that-data-class-has-changed/2123763#2123763)).

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what GUI framework (WinForms, WPF) you are using, but there is the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. There is an [How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) guide on MSDN too.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the built-in `System.EventHandler`.  That is a pretty standard pattern.  You still need to define an event for each property that you want to monitor, but you don't need a separate delegate.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms there are several ways to notify GUI when some properties are chaged using Data Binding.

There are several types of Data binding in Windows Forms.

1. For simple data binding (data source with one object boud to one control) you can use INotifyPropertyChanged, or you can add events in this format: PropertyName*Changed* for every property that you want update in GUI. And you should set [Binding.ControlUpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.controlupdatemode.aspx) property to OnPropertyChanged.
2. For complex data binding (data source with many objects bound to control that can display many objects) you should use all from (1) and you should use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) or [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) or manually implement [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx);

For more information you should see this great books:

[Windows Forms 2.0 Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267966) by Chris Sells
[Data Binding with Windows Forms 2.0: Programming Smart Client Data Applications with .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032126892X) by Brian Noyes